# copy timestamp from AWS iot rule to Amazon redshift table column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-iot

My current iot design is `iot > rule > kinesis firehose > redshift`
I have iot rule as

```
 SELECT *, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM 'topic/#
```

I get json message something like below

```
{
    "deviceID": "device6",
    "timestamp": 1480926222159
}
```

In my redshift table I have a column `eventtime as Timestamp`
Now i want to store the json timestamp value to eventtime column, but it gives me error as it needs

> TIMEFORMAT AS 'MM.DD.YYYY HH:MI:SS

for timestamp.  So how to covert the iot rules timestamp to redshift timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to converting epoch date value while inserting it to Redshift table `Timestamp` datatype column.

I have created a column with `Bigint` datatype and inserting epoch value directly to this column.
After that I am using `Quicksight` for analytics so I can edit my dataset and create New calculated field for this column and use `Qucksight function` as below

> epochDate(epoch_date)

which converts the epoch value to timestamp field.

One can use similar functions like

```
SELECT 
  (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + myunixtimeclm * INTERVAL '1 Second ')
  AS   mytimestamp
FROM 
  example_table
```